# C# - Pass string to textbox in web page using the webbrowser control

Tags: c#, string, browser, html

Is there a way to take the value of a string and pass that to a textbox within a web page while using the webbrowser control?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
doc.GetElementById("myId").SetAttribute("Value", "someValue");
```

try this

Comment: Thanks.  Another tiny related question.  How would I press a button within a webpage as well?

Comment: invoke click like this..webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myBtn").InvokeMember("click");

Comment: Whoops, meant to update this.  I got it shortly after I asked.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
String newValue = "Sample Text";
HtmlElement txt = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ElementIdOnHtmlPage");
txt.SetAttribute("value",newValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the browser automation in C# for WebBrowser control.

[Here's the reference article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mshtml_automation.aspx) explaining how you can do that.

**http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/mshtml_automation.aspx**

Comment: Note that this article is not discussing the built in Windows.Forms.WebBrowser control

Comment: Still however it is possible to use this approach with the standard WebBrowser control by casting the webBrowser .Docuemt.DomDocument property to mshtml.HtmlDocumentClass