# How do I fill in the TextBox with text on the page of website using WebBrowser and then click a Button on the site?

Tags: c#, html, .net, winforms

The link is a group I opened for testing.

[my group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/993071237423013/)

The code in the constructor:

```
webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;     
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com/groups/993071237423013/");
```

Then in the DocumentCompleted event:

```
if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri != webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri)
{
    return;
}
HtmlElementCollection items = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
{
    if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "_209g _2vxa")
    {
        item.SetAttribute("value", "אני לבדיקה 123");
    }
}
var elems = wb.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button");

foreach (HtmlElement elem in elems)
{
    if (elem.InnerText == "Post")
    {
        elem.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

But I can't pass the first line:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
```

I pass it but it's never find the className and never set the text in the textbox say Write something on the web page.

When I make Inspect element on the textbox to write something i see:

```
<div data-block="true" data-offset-key="72l55-0-0" class="_209g _2vxa">
    <span data-offset-key="72l55-0-0">
        <span data-text="true">This is CLEAR</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

And This is CLEAR is what I typed in the text box say Write something
I see the class _209g _2vxa but it's not passing inside the line:

```
if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "_209g _2vxa")
```

What I want is set a text in the box Write something and the to click the button Post

I was success doing it in my main facebook wall but when I'm in my group I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Instead of `"className"` find `"class"` attribute.

Comment: Tried now "class" didn't work either.

Comment: I didn't say it will work by using `class` but it is the first problem of your code :)

Comment: Ah ok hehe :) i will look at it again.

Comment: Also you can use `GetElementsByClassName`

Comment: Also in the html code in the question, I can't see any `TextBox` and so `item.SetAttribute("value", "אני לבדיקה 123");` makes no sense and probably will not work.

Comment: This SetAttribute worked on facebook wall i could post. Added text to to the box and posted. But maybe i'm doing it all wrong.

Comment: The text box i mean when i open a new group in facebook and then posting in the group. Any group.

Comment: When searching in stackoverflow how to pass text to box in facebook i see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598780/c-sharp-pass-string-to-textbox-in-web-page-using-the-webbrowser-control

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that you can simply implement this using the WebBrowser control.

Alternatively, you could try implementing your functionality with the [DotNetBrowser](http://teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser) component (I am one of its developers).

The way to do this in DotNetBrowser:

```
// Setting value for an input
browser.GetDocument().GetElementById("some_input").SetAttribute("value", "some_value");

// Executing Javascript code
browser.ExecuteJavaScript("someAction();");
```