# C# web browser fill com box on selected change

Tags: c#, winforms

i have got 3 html drop down list the second drop down get its values on first changed and the third gets its value on second changed how can i pass the values to combox using webbrower control and handle the same thing on combox1 value or index changed the second combox2  set new values and so on the third i had trial this is the html code and my trial ? thanks for all .

------DropDown1-------

------DropDown2-------

------DropDown3-------

```
        <select name="DDL1" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DDL1\',\'\')', 0)" id="DDL1">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">select from list </option>
            <option value="1">v1 </option>
            <option value="2">v2</option>
            <option value="4">v3</option>
            <option value="5">v4/option>
            <option value="6">v5<option>

        </select>
 <select name="DDL2" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DDL1\',\'\')', 0)" id="DDL2">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">select from list2 </option>

</select>
<select name="DDL3" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'DDL3\',\'\')', 0)" id="DDL1">
    <option selected="selected" value="0">select from list3 </option>
</select>
```

```
  foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select"))
                {
                    if (el.Id == "DDL1")
                    {
                        foreach (HtmlElement comboItem in el.Children)
                        {
                            comboBox1.Items.Add(comboItem.InnerText);
                            if (comboItem.InnerText == "select from list")
                            {
                                comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboItem.InnerText;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598780/c-sharp-pass-string-to-textbox-in-web-page-using-the-webbrowser-control

Comment: thanks its different

Answer (score 0):

Use this;

```
HtmlDocument doc = this.webBrowser1.Document;
doc.GetElementById("myId").SetAttribute("Value", "someValue");
```

I got the code from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598780/c-sharp-pass-string-to-textbox-in-web-page-using-the-webbrowser-control), I hope that helps :)

Comment: the value is changeable on selected change it reload the page and so it fill the second on the new value how i can make the same  when i change the selected from the frist combo box it reload the page on the changed and fill my second combox on the new value i work with web brower control c# windows form ?